# ERROR while starting node js npm

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

/home/sushant/Desktop/updatedProject/YouthstartApis/youthstar/Admin/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: 2: /home/sushant/Desktop/updatedProject/YouthstartApis/youthstar/Admin/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: 0025: not found
/home/sushant/Desktop/updatedProject/YouthstartApis/youthstar/Admin/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: 3: /home/sushant/Desktop/updatedProject/YouthstartApis/youthstar/Admin/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: 5f93c1abf58a33d6f0868bbe51ddce0f: not found
/home/sushant/Desktop/updatedProject/YouthstartApis/youthstar/Admin/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: 4: /home/sushant/Desktop/updatedProject/YouthstartApis/youthstar/Admin/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: ../nodemon/bin/nodemon.js: not found

npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! Admin@0.0.0 start: `nodemon --watch src ./bin/www`

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the Admin@0.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sushant/.npm/_logs/2018-06-28T18_53_17_499Z-debug.log

Comment: Please do not post an error dump with no supplementing code or context and expect your question to be well received.

Comment: Format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you dont have nodemon installed try running this before start: npm install -g nodemon

Comment: Thank you. error is solved by installing nodemon globally.